# Django query on multiple related objects

Tags: django, django-orm

I'm having trouble doing a query spanning between a lot of models.

This is the query I do to display all animals and their corresponding vaccines with encounter.status 'in-progress' and the date immunization date is in the futur.

```
def current_with_futur_vaccines(self):
    return (
        Encounter.objects.filter(
            status="in-progress").filter(
            subject__immunizations__recorded__gte=datetime.now(),
        )
        .select_related("subject")
        .prefetch_related("subject__immunizations", "location")
    )
```

The things is when I want to list the immunizations from the query I get all the immunizations for this animal and not only the immunizations that have to take place in the futur.

```
{% for immunization in object.subject.immunizations.all %}
     {{ immunization }}
{% endfor %}
```

This is the model

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Encounter(models.Model):
        subject = models.ForeignKey(Animal, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        status = models.CharField(max_length=11)

class Vaccine(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Immunization(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(
        Animal, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="immunizations"
    )
    recorded = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    vaccine = models.ForeignKey(Vaccine, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

EDIT 
When I call all() I don't expect to have all the results related to the FK. What I want is the results filtered by the query. In my example I have all the encounters filtered with recorded date in the futur but when I can the related Imunization entries with .all() I don't get the filtered Immunization results filtered by recorded but all of them.

EDIT 2:

I think I have figured it out by using a filtered prefetch. Something like this.

```
def current_with_futur_vaccines(self):
    immunizations_prefetch =  models.Prefetch("subject__immunizations", Immunizations.objects.filter(recorded__gte=datetime.now())
    return (
        Encounter.objects.filter(
            status="in-progress").filter(
            subject__immunizations__recorded__gte=datetime.now(),
        )
        .select_related("subject")
        .prefetch_related(immunizations_prefetch, "location")
    )
```

Comment: filtering on recorded ? it is not in your model. probably you forgot to include it here in your model.

Comment: Fixed it :)
And edited to add some infos.

Comment: but in your template, you run a query without the filtering.

Comment: That's what I don't want. How can I loop over only the corresponding Immunization ? Instead of .all() I have to do .filter() ? But in this case it means I have to loop through every Encounter result and then I have to filter Immunization. This would make a lot of query because for each row I have to make a new query to filter the Immunization I need. This is not performant. The SQL query generated by Django return the correct set of data but I don't know how to access it because of this .all()

Comment: I Though Django would return somethings like Encounter.subject.immunization_set()

Comment: when creating your view, do the query and then pass the results to the rendering function and process the results in template instead of making the query in template

Comment: the def current_with_futur_vaccines(self): is called in a view and I pass the resulting QuerySet to the template.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a Foreign Key/M2M reference to Immunizations in you Animal Model.

Comment: In Immunization there is a FK to Animal so I guess it's OK. When I execute the raw sql query in the database I have the correct result. It looks like when I call object.subject.immunizations.all the all() part calls every objects and not only the ones coming from the main query.